# Confused by Example in Herstein's "Topics in Algebra"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The following comes from I.N. Herstein's "Topics in Algebra", just after defining subgroups. He gives the following example

> Let $S$ be any set and $A(S)$ be the set of one-to-one mappings of $S$
>   onto itself, made into a group under the composition of mappings. For
>   any $x_0 \in S$ define $H(x_0) = \{ \phi \in A(S) : x_0\phi = x_0\}$.
>   $H(x_0)$ is a subgroup of $A(S)$. If $x_1 \neq x_0 \in S$, what is
>   $H(x_0) \cap H(x_1)$?

To me it seems like $H(x_0)$ is just the trivial group $\{e\}$, since
$$ x_0\phi = x_0 = x_0e \implies \phi = e$$
by left cancellation. Am I wrong? If so, can you help me devise a counterexample? If I am right, do you have any idea *why* Herstein chose such a trivial example?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Although the argument in the question is wrong, the conclusion remains correct for $n=3$.

Comment: Indeed! I was too cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x_0$ is not a group element you cannot cancel it. Remember $\phi\in A(S)$ and $x_0\in S$.

The group $H(x_0)$ is called the stabilizer; it is the set of all functions that fix $x_0$. Obviously in general more than one bijection on a set $S$ can fix a given point. For example on the set of reals the three bijections $x\mapsto x$ (identity), $x\mapsto -x$ (negation) and $x\mapsto x^3$ (cubing) all fix $0$, but clearly these three functions are all distinct from each other.

Comment: Oh obviously, gosh what a bad oversight... I'm going to go get some coffee. Thanks anon.

Comment: Hi, I have some additional questions regarding this example. I hope you would like to go through my post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061856/more-questions-regarding-example-i-n-hersteins-topics-in-algebra

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the subgroup $H(x_0)$ represents the mappings in $A(S)$ that fix the specific element $x_0$.  Elements of $H(x_0)$ are not required to fix all elements.

Consider $S_n$, and all of the elements in $S_n$ that leave $n$ fixed.  This is a copy of $S_{n-1}$ inside of $S_n$, and in your notation, it is the subgroup $H(n)$.