# More questions regarding example I. N. Herstein's *Topics in Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was reading I. N. Herstein's *Topics in Algebra* and had confusion in the same example as the following post:

[Confused by Example in Herstein's "Topics in Algebra"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523734/confused-by-example-in-hersteins-topics-in-algebra)

I, however, want to discuss whether $H(x_0)∩H(x_1)$ is a subgroup or not for $x_1≠x_0∈S$. Is $H(x_0)∩H(x_1)$ (or perhaps in some cases) an empty set, and hence not a subgroup? Or $H(x_0)∩H(x_1)$ gives us identity element and hence a subgroup (intersection of subgroups is a subgroup - I understand this result but I don't see why I should follow only this result)...? Is it Always the case? What if the intersection has some elements other than identity s.t. closure (or any other group property) does not apply? Does such condition occur at all?........Very confused! Thanks...

Comment: In fact, the intersection of any two subgroups is itself a subgroup (try and prove this!). Hence, $H(x_0) \cap H(x_1)$ here is always a subgroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a group $G$. If $x,y\in H\cap K$, then $xy\in H$, since $x,y\in H$, and $H$ is a subgroup. Similarly, $xy\in K$. So, $xy\in H\cap K$. Also, $x^{-1}\in H$ and $x^{-1}\in K$. Again, $x^{-1}\in H\cap K$. This suffices to show $H\cap K$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: This means that $H(x_0)∩H(x_1)$ is always a subgroup by this result and this it never violates any property of group... Thank you...:)

Answer (score 0):

Some example could help, I think. Take

$$S:=\{1,2,3,4\}\;\;,\;\;\phi\,,\,\,\psi\in A(S)\;,\;\;\begin{cases}\phi(i)=i\;,\;\;\forall\;i\in S\\{}\\\psi(1)=3\;,\;\;\psi(3)=1\;,\;\;\psi(2)=2\;,\;\;\psi(4)=4\end{cases}$$

Thus,

$$\phi\;,\;\;\psi\in H(2)\cap H(4)$$

and, in fact

$$H(1)\cap H(2)=\{\;Id=\phi\;,\;\;\psi\;\}$$

As commented here and answered in the other post, intersection ofsubgroups is **always** a subgroup, so there's not possibility at all that closure won't be fulfilled in this case.